# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' while server side rendering a react app using Static Router

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, react-static-router

I am trying server side rendering of a personal project using react static router and express. I am following official documentation of react router. When I try to run the server it shows me the following error

```
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:118:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:273:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:278:30)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21)
```

here is my code
index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

app.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navi from "./components/Nav";
import Homepage from "./components/home";
import SignIn from "./components/signin";
import SignUp from "./components/signup";
import ErrorPage from "./components/error";

function App() {
  return (
    <html>
      <title>Meetings App</title>
      <body>
        <div id="app">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navi />}>
              <Route index element={<Homepage />}></Route>
              <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />}></Route>
              <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />}></Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <script src="./index.js" />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.jsx

```
import express from "express";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
import App from "../src/App";
const http = require("http");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  res.send("<!DOCTYPE html>" + html);
});

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

From what I have researched from google, I think the problem is that what the server is trying to render is a JS file but what i am providing is HTML, though i have been unable to resolve the issue.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: And how are you compiling your React down to plain JS?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well when i started building the project i did create-react-app to build the react app. This installed Babel as a dependency. I guess babel is being used as a compiler in my project.

Comment: That builds for the client-side, not the server. The server doesn't understand JSX, it needs real JS, so that `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(...)` line won't work with JSX syntax. Give https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement#creating-an-element-without-jsx a read-through

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The documentation for React Router uses JSX on the server side as well. Here is the [reference](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/ssr#without-a-data-router). Kindly guide me if I am missing some information. I am a newbie learning to code through projects.

Comment: That page assumes [you're using Vite](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial), not create-react-app.